# sequence or not?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ratio

n= 1,2,3,4,5,6,...n
c= 1,3,6,10,,15,21,...n(n+1)/2
m= 0,1,2,4,6,9...

Am trying to find out if there a formulae that could be generated to fill in the sequence for m. I know the pattern as follows: m1+1=m2 => 0+1=1
m2+1=m3 => 1+1=2
m3+2=m4 => 2+2=4
m4+2=m5 => 4+2=6
m5+3=m6 => 6+3=9

The ratio keeps adding by 1 after every two values. 
any help towards figuring out a formula would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I have the pattern right, but how about $m_i=\big\lfloor \frac {i^2}2 \big \rfloor$?

Comment: To be clear...you appear to have strung a whole bunch of sequences together, with no clear connections between them.  I am guessing that you are just asking about the last one and I am further guessing that I have the right pattern for that one.  My sequence goes $0,1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,30,36,\cdots$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Does the sequence I proposed answer your question?  Note:  What I wrote contains a typo.  I meant to write $m_i=\big \lfloor \frac {i^2}4\big \rfloor$.

Answer (score 0):

[Found this on the encyclopedia of the integer sequences](https://oeis.org/A194164)

The formula is the following:

$$a_n=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \left\lfloor \sum_{k=1}^{j}k\sqrt3-\lfloor k\sqrt3\rfloor\right \rfloor $$

I wrote a small script on python:

[Try it here](https://repl.it/@mbs26/A194164)